# Is the exit status in PHP only useful when running from the command line?

Tags: php, command-line

I was just [reading the docs for PHP's `exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) construct.

It says you can pass an integer (0-254) which will become the exit code...

```
exit(5);
```

Is this only useful when running from PHP under CLI? Can Apache use the error code for anything? Will PHP running normally always use exit code `0`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While hardly an authoritative answer, I'm not aware of any purpose that it (passing an integer to `exit`) serves outside the CLI environment. Web servers traditionally just report the HTTP status code, and there's not any reason for them to look elsewhere for status codes.

You could take a look at PHP's source in the sapi directory. For example, in php_cli.c, you'll see `exit(exit_status);` near the end of the file. I assume the generic cgi interface uses it too. I doubt any of the web server interfaces use it.

Comment: the closer i can think of is `apache_note('exist_status', 5); exit` ... where u can get the apache variable of exist_status